# how to change text value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

i have a 2 UI Text fields, and i am trying to make it add 1 to both UI Text fields each time NextLevel method(level Completed, changes to next scene) called, For example, Text1 is 1 and Text2 is 2 and when NextLevel method called i want to change Text1 to 2 and Text2 to 3. this is my first game i tried my ways to complete this but nothing happening , please help me to complete this

```
[SerializeField] private Text Text1;
 [SerializeField] private Text Text2;

public void NextLevel()
 {
     currentStage++;
     LevelCompletedMenu.SetActive(false);
     FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().ResetBall();
     SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
     Debug.Log("Next level called");
//when this method called level will complete and load next Scene(level)
// whenever this method called i want to change Text1 value from 1 to 2 and Text2 value from 2 to 3 
and so on every time level completed, i think i need to use PlayerPrefs to save these values so that 
data passes through next scene
 }
```

Comment: rather store the values somewhere as `int` and everytime you change this value update the text fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your text value into a number, increment it, and then reassign it to your textbox.

For example:

```
TextBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)++).ToString();
```